# angularjs code to fetch the dropdown value from an html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am  comparatively new to angularjs and currently stuck with an issue.

I have a drop-down cell in an HTML table . I want to fetch that value from drop-down on click of SAVE button and save to database.

My dropdown cell using ng-options in HTML table is as below

```
<tr>
<td><select  ng-model="UserId"
    ng-options="item for item in resourceArray">
</select>
</td>
</tr>
```

My resourceArray looks like :

> ["C41113", "U16453", "C40355", "U47464", "U16087", "U41059"]

Is there a way to SAVE the value from drop-down with the help of angularJS

Please let me know if any additional details is needed.

Thanks 
Padman

Comment: `UserId` is holding that value...

Comment: you can access values at controller side as `$scope.UserId` and perform save that value.

Comment: _Is there a way to SAVE the value from drop-down with the help of angularJS_ what do you want to mention here `ng-model` directive lets you have the current value.

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada, _"save to database"_.. OP has clearly mentioned that ;)

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada He did not need to share backend details.. that was not the concern.. He wanted to access the value that is it!

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada, I did not answer it at all.. It is my decision whether to answer or not to answer..It is none of your business... ;(

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can... The $scope.UserId would give you the selected value in your dropdown.. Now for saving it into database.. you simply need to execute a $http.post("SERVER URL",{DATA}) request. You can get the data on server side and then save it to database..

Answer (score 0):

Since you have made use of `ng-model`, so you can use the same on clicking of the *Save* button:

**JS:**

```
$scope.save = function() {
    $scope.selectedValue = !$scope.UserId ? 'None' : $scope.UserId;
    alert('Selected value: ' + $scope.selectedValue);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
```

Visit the demo [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/muuL7yxb/).

Comment: wc,  if u feel it has answered,  request you to accept it as answer.